# Problem with redux auth state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

I am using react native with redux and the performance is slow. For example, on the initial page I have a check system in place, if the user in my redux state is authenticated then show home page if not show the auth screen.

When my user is authenticated, my app initially renders the auth screen for a fews seconds, then renders the Home screen, which is a bad user experience, so probably my redux state is taking time to update and is slow.

Please see my code and assist me with what I am doing wrong.

I am checking for an authenticated token in my AsyncStorage to determine an authenticated user.

## Navigation.js

```
const Root = (props) => {


    useEffect(() => {
        const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
          let token;
        //   token = null;
          try {
            token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('FBIdToken');
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
          if(token !== null){
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
            if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
              store.dispatch(logoutUser());
            } else {
              store.dispatch({ type: SET_AUTHENTICATED });
              store.dispatch(getUserData());
            }
          }
        };
        bootstrapAsync();
        setIsLoading(false);
      }, []);



    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        { 
        !props.user.authenticated ? (
            <AuthStackScreen />
        ) : (
            <DrawerScreen />
        )
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    UI: state.UI
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Root);
```

reducers.js

```
import { SET_USER, SET_AUTHENTICATED, SET_UNAUTHENTICATED } from '../types';

const initialState = {
    authenticated: false,
    loading: false,
    credentials: {},
    likes: [],
    notifications: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_AUTHENTICATED:
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticated: true
            };
        case SET_UNAUTHENTICATED:
            return initialState;
        case SET_USER:
            return {
                authenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                ...action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options

- Show a loading screen
- Turn arround the expression
- Default the authenticated to true

My prefered solution (I have done it multiple times this way):

- Create a own Screen called StartupScreen
- Do everything login-related in there
- Show an ActivityIndicator there

My example:

```
const StartupScreen = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        const tryLogin = async () => {
            const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_DATA)

            if (!userData) {
                dispatch(setDidTryAL())
                return
            }

            const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(userData)
            const {user_id, access_token, expires_at} = parsedUserData
            const expirationDate = new Date(expires_at * 1000)

            if (expirationDate <= new Date() || !access_token | !user_id) {
                dispatch(setDidTryAL())
                return
            }

            const userDetails = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_DETAILS))

            dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATE, user_id, access_token, expires_at, userDetails})
        }

        tryLogin()
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <ActivityIndicator size='large' color={Colors.primary}/>
        </View>
    )
}

export default StartupScreen
```

And my root-navigator (modern way of doing it):

```
const AppNavigator = () => {
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => !!state.auth.access_token)
    const didTryAutoLogin = useSelector(state => state.auth.didTryAutoLogin)
    
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
                { !isAuthenticated && didTryAutoLogin && <LoginAndRegisterNavigator/> }
                { !isAuthenticated && !didTryAutoLogin && <StartupScreen/>}
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    )
}
export default AppNavigator
```

For me I am not even able to see the loading-screen because the login-process is working too fast. Also the screen should just have the same background color as the ones the user will later be able to see. He will not even notice the loading-thingy.

Comment: I am also stuck in one similar issue with react navigation authentication. Can you please help me on it.